# ¿Es recomendable incluir clases como clases anidadas, o es mejor mantenerlos separados una por archivo?

Tags: java, poo, clase, arquitectura

Al crear las clases en un proyecto se tiene la opción de tener clases anidadas. 
En base a su experiencia de desarrollo **se debería crear clases anidadas en algunos casos en particular** o es preferible mantener siempre las clases de forma independiente.

*Clarificación*

**Método 1**

a.java:

```
class A{
    ...
}
```

b.java:

```
class B{
    ...
}
```

**Método 2**

a.java:

```
class A{
    ...
    class B{
        ...
    }
}
```

¿Hay casos en que método 2 ofrece ventajas sobre método 1, cuales son y hay diferencias dependiente de los modificadores usados?

Comment: no deberian cerrarla por que es una pregunta relacionado con  arquitectura de software

Comment: ¿es pregunta o son afirmaciones?

Comment: Lo encuentro una pregunta interesante y valido. Tampoco lo encuentro poco claro, por lo menos cuando uno se da la paciencia de no exigir terminología desde la especificación del lenguaje (que sería algo para explicar y aclarar en una respuesta).

Answer (score 6):

En mi opinión, depende del ámbito de esas clases anidadas.

Si deben ser visibles fuera de la clase principal que las contiene, no deben estar ahí y deben ser clases independientes.

Si son clases que se usan exclusivamente dentro de la clase principal, por ejemplo para facilitar operaciones, las dejaría dentro.

Answer (score 4):

**Acoplamiento y Cohesión**

**Que es el acoplamiento?**

Es el grado en que una clase conoce a otras clases.
es decir si la **clase A** depende de algunas funciones de la **clase B** es por que tiene **alto acoplamiento**, en este caso si queremos modificar la clase B tambien se tendra que hacer cambios en la clase A.

**Que es la cohesión?**

Es el grado en que una clase tiene uno solo objetivo, cada clase tiene que tener solo un objetivo, no hacer dos o mas objetivos por eso es programación a objetos. el grado de cohesión tiene que ser alto.

> ahora respondiendo, Es recomendable incluir varias clases en una sola
>   clase java o es mejor trabajarlas por separado?

R.- Estarias cometiendo el error de grado de cohesion bajo, por que esa clase que tiene varias clases dentro tiene varios objetivos, en realidad no lo llamaria clase, seria mas una libreria.

Cuando se programa se tiene que tener en cuenta estos dos conceptos, para que sea mas fácil mantenerlo.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo compañero , además lo que mencionas es parte de los principios SOLID que nos ayuda a desarrollar código con buenas practicas en su legibilidad , comprensión y mantenibilidad .

Answer (score 4):

La recomendación TL;DR es: En caso de duda quédate con tener cada clase en su archivo `.java`. Más que nada si trabajas solo o no tienes que considerar un largo ciclo de vida para tu código con otros que tienen que trabajar con tus clases, normalmente no vale la pena de hacerse tanto drama con el "dónde" de la declaración.

Pero hay buenas razones porque Java ofrece más posibilidades para declarar clases, y las alternativas tienen sus beneficios, si uno tiene un buen plan como aprovecharse.

En primer lugar tienes que diferenciar entre clases internas ("inner classes" - clases definidas dentro de un cuerpo de otra clase pero no `static`) y clases anidadas estáticas ("`static nested classes`" - clases definidas dentro del cuerpo de otra clase como `static`).

**Clases internas** tienen un uso práctico y obvio, porque permiten ajustar el nivel de encapsulación. Estas clases por defecto pueden usar los miembros de los objetos en que contexto fueron instados, incluyendo campos y métodos privados. Eso permite un grado alto de control sobre el acceso a miembros de la clase externa.

Además (y para que eso puede funcionar) no se puede instar una clase interna fuera de un método/constructor de la clase externa. Esta decisión de diseño vincula claramente la clase interna con la clase externa y impide "abuso" de la clase para otros contextos que podrían tener resultados inesperados.
Un buen ejemplo podría ser una clase `Validación` como clase interior de una clase `Formulario`, que valida campos de entrada del formulario en particular.

Personalmente uso regularmente clases interiores para "handler" o supervisores, de que me quiero asegurar que sean creados en el contexto concreto se un objeto de la clase exterior.

**Clases anidadas** para empezar pueden ser usado tal cual como clases declarados en sus propios archivos, **pero** tienen acceso a miembros privados de la clase exterior. Eso de nuevo me da más control sobre la visibilidad de métodos y campos, exponiendo únicamente que quiero exponer en una API.

Además las clases anidadas pueden ser declarados `private`, y así puedo limitar la generación de objetos de esta clase a métodos de fábrica en la clase exterior:

Imaginemos que tengo una clase `Nido` que puede producir una cantidad de `Dron`. Nuestros drones son trabajadores independientes, complejos y no queremos que el usuario se mete con su construcción, porque implementemos una lógica genial como reciclarlos y ponerlos al trabajo:

```
public class Nido{

    public static Runnable getDron(String mensaje){
        return new Dron(mensaje);
    }
    ...
    private static class Dron implements Runnable{
        private String mensaje;
        private Dron(String mensaje){ this.mensaje=mensaje; }
        @Override
        public void run(){
             // aqui implementemos nuestra idea genial
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return mensaje;
        }
    }
}
```

Con esta arquitectura podemos implementar un `Nido` que gestiona completamente sin permiso de intervención o abuso de un usuario de nuestra biblioteca la generación, interacción y ciclo de vida de nuestros objetos tipo `Dron`, y el usuario ni puede hacer un *cast* a `Dron`. Está básicamente limitado a llamar al método `run` y puede recibir el mensaje con `toString()`.
Mientras tanto los `Dron` pueden usar cualquier método (estático) privado de `Nido`, por ejemplo accediendo a un registro de otros `Dron` para interactuar con la clase `Nido` o entre pares.

**En resumen**:

Mientras ninguna forma de declarar clases anidadas es **necesario** para buena arquitectura, existen casos en que se pueden usar para crear control muy fino sobre restricciones de acceso y prevención de abuso sacando objetos del contexto para que fueron desarrollados. Cuando los necesitas porque chocas con limitaciones de los modificadores de visibilidad, te vas a dar cuenta y desarrollar tus propias ideas que se puede hacer con eso.

*Como ultimo aviso, restricciones a este nivel son parecido de tentador a otros programadores como "no toques este frasco, esta prohibido" para un niño de 4 años. Entonces espera que no va faltar alguien que usa hasta reflexión para hacer lo que no quisiste que pasa. Pero por lo menos lo puedes decir después: "Si perdiste tu tiempo, te lo buscaste". ;)*