# Semáforos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy practicando y aprendiendo hilos en Java. Realicé el siguiente algoritmo que cuenta con 3 clases, que no hace más que imprimir como van entrando los procesos:

La primer clase es esta:

```
public class hilo extends Thread{
    tuberia tub;
    int id; 

    hilo(tuberia tub, int id) {
        this.tub = tub;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            tub.hil(id);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    } 
}
```

La cual es el hilo. La segunda clase es mi tubería, y el código es el siguiente:

```
public class tuberia {
    int cont;

    public tuberia(int n){
        cont=1;
    }
    public synchronized void hil(int id){
        while(cont!=id){
            try{
                System.out.println("El hilo: "+id+" está intentando entrar");
                wait();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
        System.out.println("El hilo: "+id+" Entró");
        cont+=1;
        notifyAll();
    }  
}
```

La tercer y última clase, la cual es mi clase principal, es esta:

```
public class principal{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        tuberia tuber=new tuberia(10);
        hilo hilo1=new hilo(tuber, 1);
        hilo hilo2=new hilo(tuber, 2);
        hilo hilo3=new hilo(tuber, 3);
        hilo hilo4=new hilo(tuber, 4);
        hilo hilo5=new hilo(tuber, 5);
        hilo hilo6=new hilo(tuber, 6);
        hilo hilo7=new hilo(tuber, 7);
        hilo hilo8=new hilo(tuber, 8);
        hilo hilo9=new hilo(tuber, 9);
        hilo hilo10=new hilo(tuber, 10);
        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
        hilo3.start();
        hilo4.start();
        hilo5.start();
        hilo6.start();
        hilo7.start();
        hilo8.start();
        hilo9.start();
        hilo10.start();
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta aquí es la siguiente:

¿Cómo se podría implementar ese mismo programa pero con semáforos? Porque pienso que sería menos redundante, por lo que he leído de teoría, pero al mismo tiempo mientras más teoría leo, menos puedo implementarla en mi código.

Comment: amigo a que te refieres con semaforos?

Comment: Hola amigo, por favor pasa a este chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo para el modelo usando un semaforo:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * @author snolde
 *
 */
public class Tuberia {

    class Hilo extends Thread{

        int id;

        public Hilo(int id){
            this.id=id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            hil(id);
        }
    }

    static SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    Semaphore guardia;
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Tuberia(int limite){
        guardia = new Semaphore(limite, true);
    }

    public void hil(int id){
        try {
            guardia.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        synchronized(count){
            System.out.println(String.format("Hilo %d entró (%d)", id, count.incrementAndGet()));
        }

        try {
            // simulación de código productivo, carga de 500-1000 ms                Thread.sleep(500+sr.nextInt(500));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        synchronized(count){
            System.out.println(String.format("Hilo %d salió (%d)", id, count.decrementAndGet()));
        }
        guardia.release();
    }

    public void creaHilos(int num){
        for (int i = 1; i<=num; i++){
            new Hilo(i).start();
            try {
                // variable
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tuberia tub = new Tuberia(5);
        tub.creaHilos(10);
    }
}
```

Con la clase `Hilo` declarado como [clase interna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50959/es-recomendable-incluir-clases-como-clases-anidadas-o-es-mejor-mantenerlos-sep/51198#51198) no es necesario de explicitamente pasar la referencia a `Tuberia` porque tiene acceso a los métodos de la clase padre.

El contador esta incluido en bloques cortos sincronizados para garantizar que los eventos se imprimen en la sequencia que ocurren.

El [semáforo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) en el ejemplo limita la cantidad de hebras que tienen acceso al código entre `acquire` y `release`.

La diferencia principal entre las dos implementaciones es que con el semáforo hay una cantidad de hebras que pueden acceder al código en forma concurrente mientras el método sincronizado garantiza que solamente una hebra a la vez puede acceder este bloque de código, haciendolo una acción atómica.

Si eso tiene o no un sentido no es visible en un ejemplo tan básico, sin pensar en que realmente es el trabajo que hacen las hebras y que recursos necesiten para eso.

Para experimentar con el comportamiento, cambia las pausas en generación de nuevas hebras, la cantidad de hebras, la cantidad de los permisos o el tiempo aleatorio para la carga del código.